# Intersection of $X \cap Y$ where X and Y are x and y axis in $\mathbb{R^n}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was asked two questions in class. One was what would be the intersection of X and Y ($X \cap Y)$ when X and Y are x and y axis in $\mathbb{R^2}$ and the other question was the same but in $\mathbb{R^3}$.

I thought in $\mathbb{R^2}$ it would be a point (namely the origin) which is apparently wrong. In the case of $\mathbb{R^3}$ i dont know what the answer is. Does having a z axis affect the answer since the question only asks us to worry about $X \cap Y$ in $\mathbb{R^3}$ so i thought it doesnt matter if z axis exist and the answer in the case would be again a point (namely the origin).

What is incorrect about both of these cases?

EDIT: Picture of the question [Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovhlF.png)
. We are given four options from which to choose our answer. The options are A. no elements, B. one element, C. Two elements and D. Infinitely many elements

Comment: If you have stated the question correctly, then you are right in both cases. Are you sure you have quoted the question correctly?

Comment: @RobArthan I have edited the question so you can see the question as well as the given potential choices of answers

Comment: I can't see the whole questions in your graphic. But if you are sure that you have quoted the questions correctly, your answers are right.

Comment: Yes, the answer is the origin in both cases. Now if you change to $X=\{x=0\}$ and $Y=\{y=0\}$, then the answer changes when you go from $2$-space to $3$-space. In the first case, it's just the origin, whereas in the second case it now becomes the $z$-axis.

Comment: @RobArthan ive updated the picture with the options given to us. My guess for both is that it has one element.